# What is alternative solution for get user_id or screen_name querying by user e-mail

Tags: java, twitter

I am using this Twitter API extensively, but here I want to get the twitter `screan_name` or `user_id` by using email id.
I know this is not yet all possible, but please suggest me an alternative solution to achieve this requirement. I have only email-ids with me.

I am using following query to achieve this. but am getting error message like

*"Client application is not permitted to search with specified terms"*

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?email=blablabla@gmail.com.

Thank in advance.